# Google analytics integration in jquery mobile site reporting double page views for single click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile, google-analytics

I have just finished integrating google analytics on my mobile website which is based on jquerymobile. To get analytics working i am using the following code.

```
<script>
// domReady is unnecessary here and can slow down perceived performance
// $(document).ready(function (e) { 
(function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
    i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
    i[r] = i[r] || function () {
        (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
    }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
    a = s.createElement(o),
    m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
    a.async = 1;
    a.src = g;
    m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
})(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXMYID', 'mydomain.com'); // move this here!
// });

$(document).on('pageshow', '[data-role=page], [data-role=dialog]', function (event, ui) {
    try {
        if ($.mobile.activePage.attr("data-url")) {
            ga('send', 'pageview', $.mobile.activePage.attr("data-url")); // remove quotes
        }
    } catch (err) { }
});
```

While checking in Real-Time section of analytics, I each click results in double page views. Please tell me what's wrong with this code, see the picture below to understand what i am saying?

[image]

I visited four pages and analytics is showing 8 page views. How can i rectify this issue?

Comment: Do you have this site live? so that i can debug properly

Comment: Make sure your code isn't duplicate. Which JQM version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pages get over displayed as a feature on mobile devices. This is the Mobile Devices way of doing **multi-tasking** is constantly evolving, but not quite smooth. As a result, `pageshow`'s are often over-generated to ensure against under-generating.

Here are 2 approaches to handling over-event page-displaying:

**APPROACH 1**

Try adding your analytics call to `pageinit` event

```
// Every time a page is being created
$(document).on("pageinit", "div[data-role=page]", function(event){
try {
    if ($.mobile.activePage.attr("data-url")) {
        ga('send', 'pageview', $.mobile.activePage.attr("data-url")); // remove quotes
    }
} catch (err) { }
});
```

**Note:** Earlier versions recommended use is `pagecreate` event.

---

**APPROACH 2**

Another approach is to use the `one` handler to force single event handling of specific event

```
$(document).one('pageshow', '[data-role=page], [data-role=dialog]', function (event, ui) {
    try {
        if ($.mobile.activePage.attr("data-url")) {
            ga('send', 'pageview', $.mobile.activePage.attr("data-url")); // remove quotes
        }
    } catch (err) { }
});
```

---

### Follow Up

From research, I suspect your problem with mobile devices is double binding. If so, try unbinding after the event has executed:

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '[data-role=page], [data-role=dialog]', function (event, ui) {
    try {
        if ($.mobile.activePage.attr("data-url")) {
            ga('send', 'pageview', $.mobile.activePage.attr("data-url")); // remove quotes
        }
    } catch (err) { }

    $(document).off('pageshow');


});
```

Comment: i updated with this code but now it's genrating 4-5 or 6 views sometime :-P ... i guess i need to give it a day to check the working

Comment: @PankajUpadhyay, Wow, that's crazy. What platform are you using? What version of JQ Mobile? I'll do a little research to see if there are issues...

Comment: <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>  .... code is the one posted in question.

Comment: @PankajUpadhyay, apparently, this can happen on chrome 22, by events being multiple bound. try combining `one` with `pageshow`

Comment: The page views issues is getting solved by this method. But the content tracking is only showing the "/" i.e. i am not able to track the page visited

Comment: @PankajUpadhyay interesting. Are you passing distinct `page` and/or `dialog` to the event for each page?

Comment: `.one()` with `pageshow` will fire only one time on first page then it stops. `.on()` should be used instead.

Comment: @Omar using on results in double views problem stated in question

Comment: @PankajUpadhyay duplicated results aren't related to `.on()`. To make ensure you aren't getting duplicated results, you can `console.log()` inside `pageshow` event. Another issue you didn't mention in your OP, 1) JQM version 2) model used _single page_ or _multi-page_.

Comment: Still not tracking the page....anyways i am not looking more into this thing.....Thanks for your help and time dave